# Android Image Dialog/Popup same size as image and no border

Tags: android, image, dialog, popup, transparent

At the moment I am working on a file browser. Everything works fine with one exception:
If the user clicks on an image (jpg, png, bmp, ..), I want the image to be displayed in a dialog or in a popup which has the same size as the image - so that there are no borders at all.
The image files are located on the sdcard.

**Here is what I have so far:**

```
BitmapDrawable bitmap = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), TARGET_PATH);

AlertDialog.Builder imageDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.thumbnail, null);
ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_IMAGEVIEW);
image.setImageDrawable(bitmap);
imageDialog.setView(layout);
imageDialog.create();
imageDialog.show();
```

**The XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail_IMAGEVIEW"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/icon_DESCRIPTION" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Here is the output:**

[image: Fail Output]

There are ugly borders at the edges of the images - I don't want them to be shown. I tried lots of stuff and examples listed in google, etc.. - nothing worked yet.

The best option will be to make the dialog/the view behind the image, the same size as the image. Another way could be to set the background behind the image transparent.

How do I achieve any solution?
I'd love to make the background the same size as the image is, so there is no "invisible" stuff left, but I will also be okay with the transparent option.

---

**Solution:**

```
// Get screen size
Display display = context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int screenWidth = size.x;
int screenHeight = size.y;

// Get target image size
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(TARGET);
int bitmapHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
int bitmapWidth = bitmap.getWidth();

// Scale the image down to fit perfectly into the screen
// The value (250 in this case) must be adjusted for phone/tables displays
while(bitmapHeight > (screenHeight - 250) || bitmapWidth > (screenWidth - 250)) {
    bitmapHeight = bitmapHeight / 2;
    bitmapWidth = bitmapWidth / 2;
}

// Create resized bitmap image
BitmapDrawable resizedBitmap = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight, false));

// Create dialog
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.thumbnail);

ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageview);

// !!! Do here setBackground() instead of setImageDrawable() !!! //
image.setBackground(resizedBitmap);

// Without this line there is a very small border around the image (1px)
// In my opinion it looks much better without it, so the choice is up to you.
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(null);

// Show the dialog
dialog.show();
```

**XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</ImageView>
```

**Final Output:**

[image: Output]

Comment: After hours of trial and error I got it finally working. I add the solution to this first post.

Comment: Hey, I've liked your solutions so much that I abstracted it in a easy to use component https://github.com/juliomarcos/ImageViewPopUpHelper ImageViewPopUpHelper.enablePopUpOnClick(getActivity(), targetImageView);

Answer (score 2):

Change your ImageView from this:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail_IMAGEVIEW"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/icon_DESCRIPTION" />
```

To this:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail_IMAGEVIEW"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" <!-- Here is the thing -->
        android:contentDescription="@string/icon_DESCRIPTION" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: OK if it didn't work then I think you should make your own `Dialog` and apply the layout there. Because you are using the `AlertDialog` of Android so you can't change the layout. Cheers.

Comment: Yeah I did like you suggest it now - check out my first post "Solution". But thanks for your help though ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can make a custom dialog for showing images ,
make a layout for inflating in dialog's setcontentview ,
take one linear layout with width and height wrap content and imageview with in it with scale property fitxy .

Answer (score 0):

Use FrameLayout as it's parent rather than RelativeLayout and set to wrap_content and 0 margins.

Try:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@color/background">

<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:background="#b2ff7c">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The result should be a background the same size as the ImageView.

If this does work. Try modifying this in a custom theme:

```
    <style name="Widget.ImageWell">
    <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/panel_picture_frame_background</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. The result is the same as it is with my pice of code. There are still borders at the edges of the view.

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried set setType in ImageView?

`<ImageView
  ...
  android:scaleType="fitXY"
  ...
  />`

Answer (score 0):

Add single line code under your image view initialization into your activity and it will solve your problem..

```
image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```