# Trouble opening images on touching gridview

Tags: android, listview, android-imageview, onitemclicklistener

What should the code be if I want the kind of interface that is shown in the photo? When I touch the image in the ListView,it should expand ([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3R5tK.png)) and when I touch anywhere around the image, it should disappear ([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ma8cj.png)).

Comment: `What should the code be` you should write it on your own. But if you run into some specific problems - then feel free to ask questions, but please be very specific. So what is the specific problem?

Comment: Review this, You may customize as per requirement. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27954561/show-alertdialog-with-imageview-without-any-padding

Comment: @VladMatvienko I wasn't able to achieve what I have asked in the question. I'm new to all this. I'm just learning. :)

Comment: @JagdishBhavsar thanks! That was really helpful! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this using custom dialog you can achieve this

[image]

**create a custom_layout file like this**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#5a000000"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Title"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:src="@drawable/disha2" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_fill" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_fill" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_fill" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_fill" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**now in activity file add this code for custom dialog**

```
final Dialog filterDialog = new Dialog(this);
filterDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_layout);
Window window = filterDialog.getWindow();
window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,   WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
filterDialog.show();
```

**ask me in case of any query**